# Facing issue in ElasticSearch Data Visualisation

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

I am publishing data to ElasticSearch(7.4 version) in below format:

```
id: <random_id>
name: <service_name>
percent: <percentage_value>
type: <type1/type2..>
```

For each service_name, I am publishing multiple documents at different timestamp with different id, percent value, type.
I would like to create a ElasticSearch visualisation by taking top hit percent value for each service and compute average of percent values in that data.

I tried with Metric Visualisation. In data metrics section I am able to get the top hit of each service but not able to compute the average for the percent data accumulated from the top hit for all the service data.

Can someone please help me with the issue?
Thanks in advance!!